# Undefined reference to mysql while using cross-compiler and VisualGDB

Tags: c++, mysql, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile simple C++ program for Raspberry PI using VisualGDB and cross-compiler. I've done everything in the tutorial http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/wiringPi/ and managed to run sample blinking led application, so everything seems to be configured ok.

Now I want to add some mysql support to log changes and read some config info.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wiringPiSetup();

    MYSQL *mysql1 = mysql_init(NULL);


}
```

Unfortunatelly, I get en error:

```
'NULL' was not declared in this scope
```

I tried to include

```
#include <mysql/my_global.h>
```

header, so NULL was no longer undeclared, but another error showed:

```
error VGDB1000: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
```

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**

Added screenshot of my settings. TBH I don't know gcc very well... Probably that's why I'm using VisualGDB ;)

[image]

I tried adding appending this to LDFLAGS:

```
`mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs`
```

but with it I get an error:

```
Tool arguments: -Wl,--start-group "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Local\Temp\/VisualGDB_ToolchainTestProgram.o" -o "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Local\Temp\/VisualGDB_ToolchainTestProgram" -Wl,-gc-sections `mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs` -lpthread -lwiringPi -Wl,--end-group
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe: error: `mysql_config: No such file or directory
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe: error: `mysql_config: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I managed to fix the problem. I found very useful tip here: https://sysprogs.com/w/forums/topic/include-mysqlmysql-h-errorundefined-reference-to/

> You need to add the MySQL library to the ‘libraries’ setting in the VisualGDB Project Properties. Specify the name without the ‘lib’ prefix and ‘.a’ suffix. E.g. if the library name is libmysql.a, simply specify ‘mysql’ in the ‘libraries’ field.
>   You may also need to put extern “C” around the include file if it does not contain it.

I tried adding "mysql" to *Library names* section but the correct name was **mysqlclient**.

There was no need to use *extern* or add LDFLAGS.

So whenever you want to add new library, check if there is proper file inside your library directory.

Thank you for the comments, they directed me to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm terribly sorry for making an extra answer for this, but I can't comment due to lack of reputation...

Mark's answer is correct and led me to this. 
However when creating a project with CMake instead of Makefile, the "Library Names" option doesn't show up in the VisualGDB settings.

You should then go to the "Properties" of the actual code containing project, go to "Exported Settings" => "Public" => "Additional Libraries". 
Here you can, just as Mark pointed out, fill in the name of the library without any additions.

I'm not sure if this is entirely the same as how Mark adds them, but it works for me on VS2019.

Answer (score -1):

`NULL` is defined in `stdio.h`, so you just need

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
```

or define it by yourself:

```
#define NULL 0
```

About the `undefined reference to 'mysql_init'`, it is not caused by define NULL.

This error is from linking step so that it means when you make the NULL valid (which is caused error from compiling step) the error from linking step will display.

Check carefully the definition of `mysql_init` in the header files.

Comment: I think it's declared somewhere inside my_global.h as including that file resolves the problem with NULL, but causes another with mysql_init...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. For what I understood, cross-compiler compiles program locally and then uploads executable to remote device. I had to synchronise raspberry libraries with local and they are all found on my C:/ drive inside SysGCC folder. So I'm 99% sure these errors come from linker that is unable to find needed libraries despite Visual Studio / VisualGDB addon locating them correctly. I've edited my question, please, have a look.